# What should be the right h1 tag?

Tags: seo, h1

I have two `<h1>` tags on a website.

1. Every page is the logo of the site
2. The article headline of the page.

I know having more than one `<h1>` tags per page is a bad practice. Should I remove the `<h1>` tag from the logo?

Comment: Is your logo really a heading?

Comment: @JohnConde: No but it was there done by the previous developer.

Comment: Never use an h1 for a site logo. Never. It is a waste of potential that gives you absolutely nothing. The h1 tag should he the post title. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove the `h1` tag from the logo, a common error is to use it just to use its styling but it has no sense from a semantic point of view.

An `h1` element represents the heading with the highest rank for a section, so it makes sense to use it for a title.

Comment: Marcanuy says the truth. If i can suggest something, you can use span instead of h1 for Logo, if your Logo is based on a typo design, if is an image you can use `div img src="yourlogo.png"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about semantic HTML and the document outline, it makes sense to use `h1` for the logo (assuming that the logo represents the site name).

Why? See the next three steps.

#### 1. Without headings

A simple, common HTML5 document without headings could look like:

```html
<body>
  <header><!-- site-wide header --></header>
  <main><article><!-- page-specific main content --></article></main>
  <nav><!-- site-wide navigation --></nav>
  <footer><!-- site-wide footer --></footer>
</body>
```

We have three *sections* here:

1. The `body` (sectioning root)
2. The `article`
3. The `nav`

In the document outline, each section gets an entry (which is, semantically, equivalent to a heading). So the outline, without using any heading elements, is:

```
1. untitled <body>
  1.1 untitled <article>
  1.2 untitled <nav>
```

#### 2. With headings for `article` and `nav`

Now let’s give the `article` a heading element. It doesn’t matter which one, but [HTML5 recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987792/1591669) to use a heading element that corresponds to the nesting level, i.e., `h2` in this case: `<h2>My first blog post</h2>`.

And for the sake of this example, let’s give the `nav` a heading, too (`h2` for the same reasons), although it typically doesn’t need one if it’s the only navigation: `<h2>Navigation</h2>`

So we have:

```html
<body>
  <header><!-- site-wide header --></header>
  <main>
    <article>
      <h2>My first blog post</h2>
    </article>
  </main>
  <nav>
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
  </nav>
  <footer><!-- site-wide footer --></footer>
</body>
```

The document outline doesn’t change, it just gets labels:

```
1. untitled <body>
  1.1 "My first blog post"
  1.2 "Navigation"
```

#### 3. … and for `body`

**But what is with the untitled `body` entry?** It *longs* for a heading! What heading could it possibly get? The site name! Why? Because the page doesn’t contain page-specific content (like the main content) only, but also site-wide content (like the header, the footer, and the navigation). And a site heading allows us to represent this in the outline.

So the heading for the `body` sectioning root would typically be the site name (`<h1>Alice’s blog</h1>`), which can of course also be a logo (`<h1><img src="logo.png" alt="Alice’s blog" /></h1>`).

This gives us:

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1><img src="logo.png" alt="Alice’s blog" /></h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <article>
      <h2>My first blog post</h2>
    </article>
  </main>
  <nav>
    <h2>Navigation</h2>
  </nav>
  <footer><!-- site-wide footer --></footer>
</body>
```

Which results in this outline:

```
1. "Alice’s blog"
  1.1 "My first blog post"
  1.2 "Navigation"
```

---

My answers to related questions:

- [<h1> - Semantic impact vs. SEO impact](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/83075/17633)
- [For SEO of the company name, should we use a logo with alt text or a company name div replaced in CSS with an image?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86758/17633)
- [Should we use <nav> for global navigation since it is sectioning content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98477/17633)

Comment: Except a `<h1>` that is only an image is not readable text and search engines can't do anything with it, though the alt attribute can help. A better idea is to either use pseudo elements for the image and text inside the `<h1>`. There are those rare times when an image will not download or disappear altogether. Always use text. btw, there is no closing slash for the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @Rob: As [explained in my linked answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86758/17633), the logo is content, so HTML should be used for it, not CSS. The `alt` attribute does exactly do its job, giving a text representation (in case the logo contains the site name), and every somewhat sophisticated search engine should be able to handle it. -- Regarding the closing slash: We already had this discussion ;-) It’s optional in the HTML syntax, and required in the XHTML syntax.

Comment: An image is always presentation and never content of a heading element. The alt attribute is there in case the image is missing and not a stand-in for the image in an outline. And I'll say again about the closing slash. It is not optional. It's not in the spec for any HTML tag and never has been. It's allowed but does nothing and ignored.

Comment: @Rob: 1) It’s not correct that an "image is always presentation". Some images are, some are not. 2) And it’s not correct that an image should never be part of a heading. Depending on context, it might be a bad practice, but it can be perfectly fine, semantic, intended, useful. 3) I agree that it’s not a stand-in for the outline (and outline parsers would probably not display the `alt` value), but it’s what we have to work with if the author doesn’t also have the site name as text. Here CSS could be used to hide an additional text `span`, containing the site name, next to the `img` logo.

Comment: @Rob: Regarding closing slash: I already gave you a link to the relevant section in the spec in our last discussion, but you had arbitrary requirements that something like that would have to be noted in a specific other section of the spec (which is not the case). Feel free to create a question about this (although you just said that it’s "allowed", and by definition that means that it *is* part of the spec).

Comment: You are confusing an exception as the rule. The rule specifically does not show a closing slash anywhere in any HTML spec ever. Interestingly enough, you should see this: https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/737

Comment: Also, the HTML spec states, specifically, that heading elements are to contain "phrasing content" which is also defined as: "Phrasing content is the text of the document"

Comment: @Rob: … and the `img` element is [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/dom.html#phrasing-content). ··· I don’t see how "exception" vs. "rule" is relevant here; I stated that the closing slash in the `img` element is optional in the HTML syntax, and required in the XHTML syntax, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Optional means you have a choice. The spec for `<img>` does not give you that option. It is in a totally different section that states the exception and the reasoning behind the exception is too long to fit here but deals with compatibility with legacy markup that should not be used. `<img>` is phrasing content but, also as the spec states, the `<hx>` elements are to contain text but you are allowed to decorate that text: "as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. "